# Why is my y-axis inverted when using meshgrid?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-15, 15, 10)
y = np.linspace(-15, 15, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = Y;
# Z = X;
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'b'])
bounds = [-300, 0, 300]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
plt.figure();
plt.xlabel('x');
plt.ylabel('y');
im = plt.imshow(Z,cmap= cmap, norm = norm)
plt.show();
```

If I try to do Z = X, it works fine. But if I do Z = Y, the y-axis is inverted, i.e. red (negative) at the top, and blue (positive) at the bottom. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverted compared to what?

The plot you have is working fine in both cases, as expected. The value of `Z[0,0]`, which is `-15` in this case, is plotted in red at the coordinate `0,0`.

If you want the y axis to start at the bottom instead of the top, use the [`origin="lower"` keyword argument](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_origin.html) to `imshow`.